# How to Trigger an event in Laravel pusher

Tags: laravel, events, pusher

I have an issue with Laravel Pusher events

first of all

when I fire the event from the pusher debug console it works fine

But when I try to do it from my laravel controllers, it doesn't.

and here is my code

my event

```
class FileAdded implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('file.add');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'my-event';
    }
}
```

my pusher client side

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

            var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxxx', {
                cluster: 'eu'
            });

            var channel = pusher.subscribe('file.add');
            channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
                alert('hi');
            });
```

where I'm -supposedly- triggering my event

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        event(new FileAdded());

        //some unrelated stuff happen in that function
    }
```

and here is my console

> Pusher :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"]
> pusher.min.js:8 Pusher :  :
> ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-eu.pusher.com:443/app/b7f91be243251ea13075?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.0.3&flash=false"}]
> pusher.min.js:8 Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> connected
> with new socket ID 131587.15868131"] pusher.min.js:8 Pusher :  :
> ["Event
> sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"","channel":"file.add"}}]
> pusher.min.js:8 Pusher :  : ["Event
> recd",{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"file.add","data":{}}]
> pusher.min.js:8 Pusher :  : ["No callbacks on file.add for
> pusher:subscription_succeeded"]

So what could be the problem and thanks in advance!

Comment: guys if is there anything that is not clear it's probably my fault, so ask for clearance and I will provide any

Comment: have you made your listener in laravel? I did the approach where I generate events from eventserviceprovider and it worked while I included a listener